# How to wrap a try catch or other error handling around this

Tags: php

I'm a little new to OOP in PHP. I was putting together an ip to location code from MaxMind, and wanted to wrap some error handling around it, because if you supply it with an incorrect IP address, or the database is corrupt, it'll throw a fatal error.

Most of my code is stock code, but I cannot get the error handling part correct.

Here's the stock code. The idea here is to set `$countryCode = 'UN'` and `$countryName = 'Unknown'` initially, and then, if the script works, set it to `whatever` depending on the Ip address supplied.

**Stock Code**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\vendor\autoload.php');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$countryCode = 'UN';
$countryName = 'Unknown';

$reader = new Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\geoip\GeoLite2-City.mmdb');

$record = $reader->city('24.22.173.253');
$countryCode = $record->country->isoCode . '<br>'; // 'US'
$countryName = $record->country->name . '<br>'; // 'United States'

echo $countryCode;
echo $countryName;
```

**I tried**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\vendor\autoload.php');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$countryCode = 'UN';
$countryName = 'Unknown';

try{
$reader = new Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\geoip\GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
}
catch(Exception $e)
  {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }

$record = $reader->city('24.22.173.253');
$countryCode = $record->country->isoCode . '<br>'; // 'US'
$countryName = $record->country->name . '<br>'; // 'United States'

echo $countryCode;
echo $countryName;
```

**However, this is what I'm trying to do:**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\vendor\autoload.php');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;


$countryCode = 'UN';
$countryName = 'Unknown';

**If (the below is successful -> the db is successfully opened)**
$reader = new Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\geoip\GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
then (proceed with the below){
$record = $reader->city('24.22.173.253');
$countryCode = $record->country->isoCode . '<br>'; // 'US'
$countryName = $record->country->name . '<br>'; // 'United States'
}
else
//Send an email to the admin here

echo $countryCode;
echo $countryName;
```

I cant use if() here, how is this done using try catch? In all there's no need to halt the script. Let the default values of $countryCode and $countryName remain if the i[ detect does not succeed.

**The code in the MaxMind script is done this way:**

```
if (!filter_var($ipAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                "The value \"$ipAddress\" is not a valid IP address."
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any line within a `try` block throws an exception, future lines are not ran and the `catch` block is ran instead.  So you can safely move those lines into the `try` block:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\vendor\autoload.php');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$countryCode = 'UN';
$countryName = 'Unknown';

try {
    $reader = new Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\geoip\GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
    $record = $reader->city('24.22.173.253');
    $countryCode = $record->country->isoCode . '<br>'; // 'US'
    $countryName = $record->country->name . '<br>'; // 'United States'
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Send an email to the admin here instead of echo'ing $e->getMessage()
    // if that's what you want to do.
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

echo $countryCode;
echo $countryName;
```

Now, if the first line of the `try` block throws an exception, the other three lines won't be executed.  Instead, the `catch` block will be executed.  So that is where you can send your email to the admin.

(If the `$reader =` line throws an exception, the `$record =` line will *not* be executed, nor will subsequent lines within the `try` block.)

Comment: Much like what I did. Thing is, I'm also trying to add a `try` inside that `try` around the `$record=` part. So, the `$record=` part will run only if the `$reader=` part succeeds.

Comment: You don't understand, Norman... In the code as I've written it here, -indeed-, the `$record=` line will ONLY be executed if the `$reader=` line does -not- throw an exception.  If the `$reader=` line throws an exception, PHP will -jump out- of the `try` block and into the `catch` block before any other lines of code are executed.

Comment: I see you're correct. So I was almost there. No need of wrapping another try around `$record` then?

Comment: @Norman Correct - if the `$reader =` line succeeds, but then the `$record =` line throws an exception, then the `catch` block will be executed after it and the subsequent two lines of code will not be executed.